# Syscall to new server in Minix 3.2.1

Tags: server, system-calls, minix

I implemented a new server in minix. It seems to work fine, after "service up..." it is up and waits for messages. In client file:

1)I get endpoint with minix_rs_lookup("serverName",*pt)

2)call _syscall(pt,...)

After that I'm getting:

sys_call: ipc mask denied SENDREC from number1 to number2

I searched through minix code and it seems that my process "may not" call this service.

Could anyone explain me why does it happens so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with configuration file. I didn't give enough permissions there.

Comment: Could you tell which configuration file is that? I have the same problem and I'm thinking it has to do with `system.conf`, but changing `ipc`, `sigmgr`, `system`, nothing helps.